# Make some equation numbers bold

Tags: equations, numbering, bold

I would like to make some equation numbers (that will be defined *ad hoc*) **bold**, while others are not. I can only figure out how to make all **bold** or unbold, not what I am looking for.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm, amscd}
\usepackage[a4paper, textwidth=39cm, margin=1.2in, vmargin=3cm, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=.6in,]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\renewcommand\theequation{\bfseries\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x-y=z
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you want to deal with cross-references to various equations: should the cross=refs also appear in bold in case the equation numbers of the corresponding equations happened to be set in bold?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I am aware, the only way to do this is to keep on turning bold off and on every time that you want to do this. The cleanest solution would be to define a new version of `equation` that automatically makes the equation number bold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\newenvironment{boldequation}{\renewcommand\theequation{\textbf{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}}\equation}
   {\endequation}

\begin{boldequation} 1+1=2 \end{boldequation}

\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Alternatively, a cruder way of doing this is using "switches" like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\boldequations{\renewcommand\theequation{\textbf{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}}}
\newcommand\normalequations{\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}}

\boldequations
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\normalequations
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: You also can define a `\newtagform{bold}` that define equation numbers as bold, and write in  your equation `\usetagform{bold}`. This requires only the `mathtools` package that you may already use.

Comment: @Bernard Yours is more than a comment

Answer (score 4):

Let me detail my comment: the `mathtools` package defines `\(re)newtagform` commands that help define tag ‘styles’. Then `\usetagform{name}` is a switch to be used outside a math environment. You may go back to the usual style with `\usetagform{default}`.

In addition, I define a command that allows to change the tag style for `one` equation of a multiline group of equations in order to, say, emphasize that particular equation. The definition of this command is not generic, as `\usetagstyle` will not work in this context, so that you will have to change its definition if you want to change the style.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtagform{coloured}[\bfseries]{\color{red}(}{\mdseries)}
\newcommand\boldtag{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag*{(\textbf{\color{red}\theequation})}}

\begin{document}

\usetagform{coloured}
\begin{align}
 a & = b + c \\
 a^2 & = b^2 + c^2
\end{align}

\usetagform{default}

\begin{align}
 a & = b + c \\
 a^2 & = b^2 + c^2 \boldtag \\
 a^3 & =b^3 + c^3
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]