# this is the work I need to reproduce, kindly help with the coding

Tags: diagrams, enumerate, tikz-trees, graphs, greek

[image: volvo4]

The page above has work am trying to reproduce but the Greek numeration with marks in parentheses(bold) and the tree diagram have given me trouble. I don't seem to be getting it right. Am new to latex, so kindly help me.

Comment: dumplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237483/201158

Comment: And the question about Greek-letter numbering is an out-and-out duplicate of [How do I use Greek letters to enumerate a list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/552332/5001)

Answer (score 5):

Just like an exercise, I think that your graph is done with `tikz-cd`, but I can do some mistakes. You can draw also with `istgame` package, or with tikz tree/`forest`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1cm,column sep=2cm]
& & & 103.68 \\
& & 86.4 \arrow[ru] \arrow[rd] &  \\
&  72 \arrow[rd] \arrow[ru] & & 77.76  \\
60 \arrow[ru] \arrow[rd] &  & 64.8 \arrow[ru] \arrow[rd] & \\
& 54 \arrow[ru] \arrow[rd] &  & 58.32  \\
& & 48.6 \arrow[ru] \arrow[rd] & \\
& & & 43.74 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I think your output is very similar to this:

[image]

If you see some bit differences you can try to modificate the values of `row sep=1cm,column sep=2cm`.

For further your request you can see these link (for example):

1. [Problem with enumeration using greek letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342498/problem-with-enumeration-using-greek-letters/342531;)
2. [Make some equation numbers bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/make-some-equation-numbers-bold)

Answer (score 2):

A solution with a `psmatrix` for the tree. For the enumeration with Greek letters, I defined a  `\greek{counter}` command, so the `enumitem`  package  accepts the key `label=\greek*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\def\@greek#1{%
 \ifcase#1\or%
 \ensuremath{\upalpha}\or
 \ensuremath{\upbeta}\or
 \ensuremath{\upgamma}\or
 \ensuremath{\updelta}\or
 \ensuremath{\upvarepsilon}\or
 \ensuremath{\upzeta}\or
 \ensuremath{\upeta}\or
 \ensuremath{\upvartheta}\or
 \ensuremath{\upiota}\or
 \ensuremath{\upkappa}\or
 \ensuremath{\uplambda}\or
 \ensuremath{\upmu}\or
 \ensuremath{\upnu}\or
 \ensuremath{\upxi}\or
 \ensuremath{\upomicron}\or
 \ensuremath{\uppi}\or
\ensuremath{\uprho}\or
\ensuremath{\upsigma}\or
 \ensuremath{\uptau}\or
 \ensuremath{\upupsilon}\or
 \ensuremath{\upvarphi}\\or
 \ensuremath{\upchi}\or
 \ensuremath{\uppsi}\or
 \ensuremath{\upomega}\else
 \@ctrerr\fi}%
\def\greek#1{\expandafter\@greek\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\AddEnumerateCounter\greek\@greek{m}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{15}


\begin{enumerate}[label=(\greek*),font=\bfseries\boldmath]
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{enumerate}

\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5cm, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.1, nodesepA=3pt, nodesepB=2pt]
 & & & 103.68 \\
  & & 86.4 \\
 & 72 & & 77.76 \\
60 & & 64.8 \\
 & 54 & & 58.32 \\
 & & 48.6 \\
  & & & 43.74
\ncline{4,1}{3,2}\ncline{3,2}{2,3}\ncline[offsetB=1pt]{2,3}{1,4}
\ncline{4,1}{5,2}\ncline{5,2}{6,3}\ncline{6,3}{7,4}
\ncline{3,2}{4,3}\ncline{4,3}{5,4}
\ncline{5,2}{4,3}\ncline{4,3}{3,4}
\ncline{2,3}{3,4}\ncline{6,3}{5,4}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Benard Which part of this answer (the codes) only deals with the binomial tree?

Comment: In the preamble: only `\usepackage{pst-node`, and in the body, the `psmatrix` environment.